# wp_customize_image_control deprecated add_tab alternative

Tags: images, theme-customizer, tabs, deprecation

I have been using add_tab to add a tab in Customizer with default images. It is deprecated and no longer works in WordPress 4.1. How can I create/find an alternative?

```
add_action( 'customize_register','add_pattern_images', 12, 1 );

function add_pattern_images( $wp_customize ) {

    $control = $wp_customize->get_control( 'aaa[backgroundpattern]' );
    $control->add_tab( 'theme_patterns', 'Theme Patterns', 'pattern_images' );

}

function pattern_images() {

    $backgrounds = array(
        '/library/images/background_pattern/background_pattern_01.png',
        '/library/images/background_pattern/background_pattern_02.png',
        '/library/images/background_pattern/background_pattern_03.png',
        '/library/images/background_pattern/background_pattern_04.png',
        '/library/images/background_pattern/background_pattern_05.png',
        '/library/images/background_pattern/background_pattern_06.png',
        '/library/images/background_pattern/background_pattern_07.png',
        '/library/images/background_pattern/background_pattern_08.png',
        '/library/images/background_pattern/background_pattern_09.png',
        '/library/images/background_pattern/background_pattern_10.png',
    );

    global $wp_customize;

    $control = $wp_customize->get_control( 'aaa[backgroundpattern]' );

    foreach ( (array) $backgrounds as $background )
        $control->print_tab_image( esc_url_raw( get_template_directory_uri() . $background ) );

}
```

Comment: I think the only way is to override the [`content_template` method](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-control.php#L739). I'm sorry but I have no more time today test how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see they comepletly changed background image ( or image ) select in customizer.

There's no more tabs for images at all.

But what can you do is create new class wich will extend WP_Customize_Image_Control ( or WP_Customize_Upload_Control ) and add there a choise ( select or radio ) to show upload or sellect pattern.

May be it can be compleated without new class, simply add_control function to add fields and litle js to show hide upload and select pattern box.

Personaly i don't like customizer, so i don't know about it much, but i'v looked to code and add_tab is gone for shore (